# Java Try and catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a java program that is supposed to handle an Exception, but the end result is far from what I intended it to be. Here is the overall idea of my program: it is supposed accept an input of zero and exit the program. The input dialog should cause an Exception which should be caught  and print the message "bad number".

My brain is telling me I'm missing one line of code in the catch block.

here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class exceptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            String line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter number");
        if(line.equals ("0"));
        System.exit(0);
        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bad number");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not catching an exception here, you are simply making a if statement, you can just use an if/else.

```
try{ 
     String line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter number");
     if(line.equals ("0")){
          System.exit(0);
     }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bad number");
     }
}catch (Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The catch you would only use for any exceptions showInputDialog() throws, but for your number check you are not catching anything, it just simply is not 0.

Comment: Hello BVSmallman, I could do it that way and it's much easier too. But the idea of my program is to utilize try and catch exceptions which makes it more challenging to do. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: There is still a semi-colon after the if statement that will cause problems.

Comment: If your goal is to catch an exception, then you need to manually throw one when it is not 0, but as it currently stands no matter what number you type in it will not throw & catch anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't execute your exception handling code because you never throw an exception.  The code will execute the input, then test the input to be equal to "0", then based on that will or will not display a dialog, and then it will execute.

The throwing of an exception occurs either because something has happened outside the conditions that the code will handle, or because you throw one explicitly.

By "outside the conditions" etc., I mean something like dividing by 0.  Java (nor any other language) will handle that, and an exception will be thrown.  The normal steps of procedural processing will stop, and an execution handler will be called.

In your case, if you (for instance) attempted to parse the input to be a number, but the input was not a number, you would get an exception.  This is different functionality than you say you wanted, but is a better illustration of what an exception is for.  Something like

```
try
{
int numberEntered = Integer.parse(line);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered a number, parsed to " + numberEntered);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Did not enter a number, but <" + line + ">");
}
```

shows the sort of thing exceptions are normally good for.

If you wanted to, you could define an exception, call it BadNumberException, and throw it in the code you have -- you would put it (I guess) in an else clause for your if statement.  But your routine would be throwing the exception, and I think it is unusual for the routine that throws an exception to also catch it.

Hope that helps.
rc

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon after your if statement, it terminates the line and the compiler does not look for the rest of the if. Remove your semi-colon and it will work fine.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class exceptTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try 
        {
            String line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter number");
            if(line.equals ("0")) //semi-colon removed here
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input was not 0");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bad number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct abut getting rid of the semi-colon, but that alone will not fix the problem (see @BVSmallman's answer).

Comment: This kind of 'works', but I don't think it will fit the OP's goal.

Comment: @Mac I see that above now, but regardless even with the else block you would still never reach it because of the semi-colon

Comment: Edited to display a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not throw an exception if the input is not equal to 0. Therefore, you never catch anything, thus no errormessage is shown on the screen.

You could do two things:
- throw an exception if the input is not 0 (then you will enter the catch)
or
- use an `else` with your `if` that displays the error message (then you don't need the try-catch for checking whether the input is 0)

Edit: And of course as Hunter McMillen noticed, you need to remove the semicolon after your if statement.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong and needed to add. Thanks my fellow programmers!